# Calling Python in Execute Process Task suddenly stopped working

Tags: python, ssis

Came back from a break and my production processes which have been running for almost a year suddenly stopped working.

I have an SSIS package which after a series of steps invokes a python script with arguments.

Python is being called from Execute Process task with Executable passed as:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe

Arguments are dynamically generated.

Running the SSIS job suddenly fails with the error message:

```
      In Executing "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe" "Z:\\Projects\\NNA\\EncryptFile.py Data_Feed 01032019" at "", The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0".
```

The process was working before --  running it independently in the command line also works, but just not from SSIS.

Any idea what could be happening?

Looked at similar issues on SO and through google search. None of the suggestions worked.

Expected Execute Process to kick off the python script. However it is failing with an error message "The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0".

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers

Comment: Where does it say its a debugging question? I don't recall choosing the type. While I do know these are vague and do not help the greater good, the reason for us posting specific questions like this is to see if anyone else in the community has encountered these sort of issues and has a fix that worked for them.

Comment: It's not a type that you choose when creating the question, but surely you agree this is a "why isn't this code working?" question.  The point of the comment is that nobody can help you answer your question without having enough information to reproduce the issue themselves.   The best anyone can do with what you've provided is guess.

Comment: Is it possible permissions changed somewhere in the Z directory? Also, is the Z directory still accessible from where the package is running? Can you try running the script manually from a command line on the server where this is deployed and see if you get a more descriptive error?